# Installing a relay and its ratings

Tags: relay

I'm planning to install [this](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/power-relays/6839239) DC input relay called G5RL-1A-E-HR-5DC at the line of an SMPS supply. The [SMSP](https://docs.rs-online.com/063b/0900766b81621f59.pdf) will sink nominal AC line current of less than 1A but its inrush is 45A at cold start.

The manual of the relay is given [here](https://docs.rs-online.com/d6a0/0900766b80dc0322.pdf). The model I plan to use is high inrush type and HR in its name means high-inrush. I also found the following table from the manufacturer site [here](https://components.omron.com/us-en/products/basic-knowledge/relays/applications):

[image]

But given all these info I have the following questions:

1. I cannot find the coil resistance for DC. What is the DC coil resistance of this relay? (G5RL-1A-E-HR-5DC so 5VDC one)
2. It says high inrush but no value. What is the inrush current this relay can handle?
3. As a flyback diode can a [1N4148](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81857/1n4148.pdf) handle 45A inrush used with this relay? What plot in the diode datasheet can we conclude that?

Comment: The 1N4148 datasheet ABSOLUTE MAXIMUM RATINGS table shows you that that diode is rated for 300 mA. The inrush current is the specification for the **contacts**. You use flyback diodes on the **coil**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That datasheet is a bit dubious, maybe it's been superseded. For example, I don't see the TV rating for a DC coil.

[Here](https://components.omron.com/us-en/datasheet_pdf/K132-E1.pdf) is the current datasheet from the manufacturer. You don't mention the mains voltage, but if I  have to guess, I'd guess it could be more than the 120VAC the TV ratings apply to, and the life of 25,000 operations may not apply.

There is a CSA/UL motor load rating of 60 LRA/10 FLA, 250 VAC, 40°C, so it should be fine for the 45A inrush (since 60A is more than 45A), but the life is given as only 6,000 operations. So, I suggest caution if your mains can exceed 120VAC and you need much more than 6,000 operations life.

Coil ratings are given in a table, so 80mA under nominal conditions for the 5V model. You should ensure it gets as close as possible to the full 5V for long life and reliable operation at high temperature:

[image]

The flyback diode across the coil just sees a brief pulse of the coil current (80mA in this case, rapidly decaying to nothing), so almost any silicon or Schottky diode will work. For example 1N4005, 1N4148, 1N5819 etc. Since even the [1N4148](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81857/1n4148.pdf) can easily handle the full coil current continuously and also easily handle the 5V reverse voltage (typically a 75V or more rating), it will work fine.

As far as *knowing* it will work fine, the voltage rating is straightforward. The current rating is given as 300mA at 25°C **absolute maximum**, so we have derate that for proper design, but 80mA is around 25% of the absolute maximum at 25°C a and it's only briefly pulsed so it won't get a chance to heat up much so it's fine.

About 1V is near the top of the scattering limit of forward voltage at 80mA in Fig 2, which means 80mW peak dissipation, which would heat it 28°C (assuming 4mm lead length in the RthJA spec). So at an ambient of 70°C the junction would only be ~100°C, which is acceptable for reliability and much less than the 175°C absolute maximum. And again, we don't have 80mA continuous, just a brief pulse when the relay drops out, so we're really good.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I didnt get the last two paragraphs. This relay is non-latched NO relay. So 80mA current is continuous to keep it closed. Why do you say “we don’t have 80mA continuous”?

Comment: Mains voltage will be mostly 230VAC and sometimes 120VAC.

Comment: Context is diode rating. The 80mA is peak *diode* current for a brief time (milliseconds) just after the relay drive is switched off.

Comment: Great your answer is very didactic.

Answer (score 2):

1. The 5VDC HR model has a coil that is rated 80.0 mA and 62.5 ohms.
2. Datasheet does not say other than up to 100 A in the marketing features. And that the HR model is rated "TV-5".
3. The flyback diode of the coil has nothing to do with the inrush current passed through the contacts.

Comment: The maximum current on the flyback diode is the coil current. So that diode will see 80mA max.